# Calculate acceleration and time given initial speed, final speed, and travelling distance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration, kinematics

A motorcycle is known to accelerate from rest to 190km/h in 402m.

Considering the rate of acceleration is constant, how should I go about calculating the acceleration rate and the time it took the bike to complete the distance?

Comment: Try v=u+at for acceleration.

Comment: But I don't know how long it took the bike to cover the stretch. I only know Vi (0), Vf (190km/h), and d (402m).

Comment: You are correct that you need more than just that equation.  The other kinematic equation you might want to use is $x=1/2 a t^2$, which uses the fact that you started from rest and had a constant acceleration.  I'd advise reading a basic kinematics tutorial online.

Comment: I advise reading ja72's answer below ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For constant acceleration, you have two equations that you need to solve for time $t$ and acceleration $a$.

$$x=\frac12at^2$$
$$v=at$$

It is up to you from here.

$$402\ \mathrm m=\frac12at^2$$
$$\left(190\ \mathrm{\frac{km}h}\right)\left(\frac{1000\ \mathrm{\frac m{km}}}{3600\ \mathrm{\frac sh}}\right)=\left(52.777\ \mathrm{\frac ms}\right)at$$